# Compile error with OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glut, glew

Here is the program that I am trying to run

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////          
// square.cpp
//
// Stripped down OpenGL program that draws a square.
// 
// Sumanta Guha.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include <iostream>

#ifdef __APPLE__
#  include <GLUT/glut.h>
#else
#  include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

using namespace std;

// Drawing (display) routine.
void drawScene(void)
{
   // Clear screen to background color.
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

   // Set foreground (or drawing) color.
   glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

   // Draw a polygon with specified vertices.
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
      glVertex3f(20.0, 20.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(80.0, 20.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(80.0, 80.0, 0.0);
      glVertex3f(20.0, 80.0, 0.0);
   glEnd();

   // Flush created objects to the screen, i.e., force rendering.
   glFlush(); 
}

// Initialization routine.
void setup(void) 
{
   // Set background (or clearing) color.
   glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
}

// OpenGL window reshape routine.
void resize(int w, int h)
{
   // Set viewport size to be entire OpenGL window.
   glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);

   // Set matrix mode to projection.
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

   // Clear current projection matrix to identity.
   glLoadIdentity();

   // Specify the orthographic (or perpendicular) projection, 
   // i.e., define the viewing box.
   glOrtho(0.0, 100.0, 0.0, 100.0, -1.0, 1.0);

   // Set matrix mode to modelview.
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

   // Clear current modelview matrix to identity.
   glLoadIdentity();
}

// Keyboard input processing routine.
void keyInput(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   switch(key) 
   {
      // Press escape to exit.
      case 27:
         exit(0);
         break;
      default:
         break;
   }
}

// Main routine: defines window properties, creates window,
// registers callback routines and begins processing.
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{  
   // Initialize GLUT.
   glutInit(&argc, argv);

   // Set display mode as single-buffered and RGB color.
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB); 

   // Set OpenGL window size.
   glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);

   // Set position of OpenGL window upper-left corner.
   glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100); 

   // Create OpenGL window with title.
   glutCreateWindow("square.cpp");

   // Initialize.
   setup(); 

   // Register display routine.
   glutDisplayFunc(drawScene); 

   // Register reshape routine.
   glutReshapeFunc(resize);  

   // Register keyboard routine.
   glutKeyboardFunc(keyInput);

   // Begin processing.
   glutMainLoop(); 

   return 0;  
}
```

I am certain I have glut and OpenGL installed and up to date, and this is the error that I am getting (I am compiling the code the way it is laid out in the book which is from 2011):

> ubuntu:~/Downloads/Code$ gcc square.cpp -o square -I
>   /usr/include/ -L /usr/lib -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lX11
>   /tmp/ccAq6h4h.o:square.cpp:function
>   __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
>   /tmp/ccAq6h4h.o:square.cpp:function
>   __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int): error: undefined reference to 'std::ios_base::Init::~Init()' collect2: ld returned 1
>   exit status

I wrote my own code and left it as a c file and it compiled

Comment: Ok the code worked when I compiled with g++ instead of gcc, is there a reason the author would say to compile using gcc instead of g++?  I am very new to this and I understand that gcc compiles as a c program but with g++ it compiles and links correctly?

Comment: If the authors told you to use gcc, they are morons. C++ **is not** C, and it's not even a superset of it. If your code is C++ you need a C++ compiler. Which is g++.

Comment: You know you are using deprecated legacy OpenGL, do you? You probably found an out-of-date tutorial. See http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was a simple error of wrong files being compiled.